# Proving that $f$ is a linear map given that it satisfies the additivity condition

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $ m, n \in \mathbb{N}$  and let $V = \mathbb{Q}^{n}$ and $W = \mathbb{Q}^{m}$ be vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose that $f : V \rightarrow W$ satisfies $\forall x, y \in V:f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$.

Say you've been given a function as seen above, such that you have the additivity condition already, how would you then prove the homogeneity condition?

So far I've considered $\lambda \in \mathbb Q$ and $x \in \mathbb Q^{n}$, giving us:
$$f(\lambda x) = f(\underbrace{x \ + \ \ldots \ + \ x}_\text{$\lambda$ times}) = \underbrace{f(x) \ + \ \ldots \ + \ f(x)}_\text{$\lambda$ times} = \lambda f(x)$$
Using the additive condition. However I'm not confident that this makes sense considering the fact that $\lambda$ is a rational number.

Comment: Hint. First show that homogeneity works for scalars of the form $1/k$.

Comment: First prove for integer case, then prove that $q f(\frac p q x)=f(px)=p f(x)$